# bootstrap form button and subscribe para floatting issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have developed a Responsive page with bootstrap . in my page i have a form where  subscribe text and submit button are floatting . i have tried a lot but i am failing to remove this issue . 
 i want buttn and subscribe text like below image 
[result which i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C82s.jpg)

but below 768px i am getting this result [result which i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9San.jpg)

HTML code :-

```
    <div class="fromdiv">
<form>
<input class ="col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-8 Frominput" type="Name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
<input class ="col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-8 Frominput2" type="Name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required>
<input class ="col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-8 Frominput3" type="Email" type="Email" placeholder="Email Address" required> </br>
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 subscribesubmit">
 <img class ="img-responsive Fromsubscribe" src="HomeImage\subscribe.png"/>
<p class ="col-md-6 col-lg-5 FromsubscribeSpan"> Safe Unsubscribe </p>
<button class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 btn btn-primary Submit_Button"> Submit </button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

and css is :-

```
.Frominput,.Frominput2,.Frominput3
{       
    margin-left: 19.5%;
    height:43px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Lato-Light;
    float:left;
}

.Frominput2,.Frominput3
{
    margin-top:18px;
}


:placeholder-shown 
{
  font-size:18px;
  font-family:Lato-Regular;
  padding-left: 2%;
}
.Fromsubscribe
{
    margin-top: 186px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Lato-Light;
    clear:both;
}
.FromsubscribeSpan
{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Lato-Light;
    margin-top:-4%;
    margin-left:0.5%;
    clear:both;

}

.Submit_Button
{
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#58A6CA;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight:Bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline-style:none;
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Lato-Hairline;
    margin-left: 68.5%;
    margin-top: -6%;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    clear:both;
}
```

please help me to solve this issue . enter code here

Comment: show your related code  ..

Comment: We need your code for resolve your problem...

Comment: i have included my html and css code for this form

Comment: You don't have a specific question, you simply got lost on a spaghetti code with bad CSS and HTML structures that don't make much sense regarding responsive design. Resolving this, in my opinion will be rebuilding the whole thing using the design provided in your question. Here's a jsFiddle if anyone wanna play with it: https://jsfiddle.net/szx3zx48/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i remake your code structure to make better responsive design. You can personalize the form with CSS.

HTML :

```
<div class="container form-container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    </div>
    <div class="left-info">
      <img class="img-responsive Fromsubscribe" src="HomeImage\subscribe.png" />
      <p>Safe Unsubscribe </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-info">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary Submit_Button">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.left-info {
  display: flex;
  float: left;
}

.right-info {
  float: right;
}

.Submit_Button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #58A6CA;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: Bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato-Hairline;
  clear: both;
}
```

DEMO :

https://jsfiddle.net/tff6Lhxz/

Comment: Thanks Mate for Help    But it is still floatting below 480 px .